# How to handle async method that has some awaits and some cpu-bound operations

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around async/await. I'm trying to figure out if I need to wrap my CPU intensive workload in a Task.Run below. Can someone tell me which is the better way to do this?

**Without Task.Run:**

```
public async Task ProcessData()
{
    //Get some data
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("myUrl");
    string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //Calculate result
    string result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        //Do some CPU intensive work
    }

    //Save results
    using (var fs = new FileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(result);
    }
}
```

**With Task.Run:**

```
public async Task ProcessData()
{
    //Get some data
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("myUrl");
    string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //Calculate result
    string result = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            //Do some CPU intensive work
        }
    });

    //Save results
    using (var fs = new FileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(result);
    }
}
```

My instinct is to not use the Task.Run but in that case would that mean that all code in an async method is going to be executed on a separate thread? Meaning the calling thread will not be interrupted until the very end (File stream is closed and method ends)?

Or will the caller thread be interrupted and go back to this method to do the CPU intensive part first and then go back to whatever it was doing while ProcessData() runs in the background for the FileStream part?

I hope that's clear.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use the `Parallel.Foreach()` for multithreaded CPU bound work. `Parallel.Foreach(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000), i => //Do some CPU intensive work);`

Comment: I dont see any difference in having a task running the cpu work compared to not having it since you await it. If you want to speed that part up on the other hand you could parallelize it, but you wouldn't use async/await and tasks for that.

Comment: Are you going to call the `ProcessData` method from an event handler of a Windows Forms or WPF application? Or will be called from inside an ASP.NET application? Btw according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the asynchronous methods are expected to have the suffix `Async`. So the `ProcessData` method should be named `ProcessDataAsync`.

Comment: This code is just a sample. I cannot use parallel.foreach because the CPU bound work is actually an external library call. For context, this is a windows service application.

Answer (score 5):

As describe in my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), an `async` method begins executing just like any other method, directly on the stack of the calling thread. When an `await` acts asynchronously, it will capture a "context", "pause" the method, and return to its caller. Later on, when the "asynchronous wait" (`await`) is complete, the method is resumed on that captured context.

So, this means:

> would that mean that all code in an async method is going to be executed on a separate thread?

[There is no separate thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). No thread at all "executes" the `await` because there's nothing to do. When the `await` completes, the method continues executing in that captured context. Sometimes this means the method is queued to a message queue, where it will eventually be run by the original calling thread (e.g., UI apps work this way). Other times this means the method is run by whatever thread pool thread is available (most other apps work this way).

> Meaning the calling thread will not be interrupted until the very end (File stream is closed and method ends)? Or will the caller thread be interrupted and go back to this method to do the CPU intensive part first and then go back to whatever it was doing while ProcessData() runs in the background for the FileStream part?

The calling thread is never interrupted.

The CPU-bound portion of the work will run on whatever "context" was captured at the point of the `await`. This can be the original thread, or it can be a thread pool thread, depending on the context.

So, back to the original question:

> Can someone tell me which is the better way to do this?

If this is code that can be called from different contexts, then I recommend not using `Task.Run`, but I do recommend documenting that the method does do CPU-bound work. That way, if a caller invokes this method from a UI thread, then it knows to use `Task.Run` when invoking it, to ensure the UI thread isn't blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stephen. I've read all your async related articles many times but I still get confused. Especially your "There is no thread" article because it's hard to wrap my head around it. Even Microsoft's own [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) call them threads. And it implies that a task will grab a thread from the thread pool meaning that if I start a task it will get executed on a different "thread". I know the thread goes back to the thread pool on an await but we're still allowing concurrency right?

Comment: Yes, [the problem is that `Task` is two completely different things](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html): it's a Promise type (as used in asynchronous programming), and it's also a kind of enhanced Delegate type (as used in parallel programming). The docs you linked to are for parallel programming, not asynchronous programming, so they're talking about the `Task` type from a completely different perspective than how you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `async` to do CPU-bound work is for [responsiveness reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth#why-does-async-help-here).

> Why does async help here?
>
> async and await are the best practice for managing CPU-bound work when you need responsiveness.

That's when, after the work has been scheduled, you need to do other work on the current thread concurrently, or you need to yield the thread back so it can do other things.

For example, typically you want to avoid CPU-bound work on UI thread / in UI synchronization context, because you could end up with a frozen / non-responsive UI. In this case, you could choose to use `Task.Run` to schedule the work to the next available thread in the thread pool.

Also, say if your code is on a thread pool thread already, it doesn't mean you should never use `Task.Run`, because there's valid reasons you could run something in parallel with the CPU-bound work.

For example, you want to do a computation, and while waiting on the result, you want to call a remote API for something else, so you could combine the results together when they both returned.

It is *really* up to your scenario. But what you might need to aware is that when you use `async` for CPU-bound work, there's small overhead cost incurred for context switching. Have that said, mind the times of context switching happens in your code.

> It's important to note that there is a small cost to using async and it's not recommended for tight loops. It's up to you to determine how you write your code around this new capability.

Comment: The small cost is not important in this case as it's a low priority windows service. I just want to know if the CPU bound code will still run on a separate thread pool thread or not. So the question is "If we have an async method, is all the code in that async method, even the CPU-bound parts, executed on a separate thread that is not the calling thread?"

Comment: @Sal "executed on a separate thread that is not the calling thread" is not guaranteed, so the answer is yes and no. It depends on whether the thread calling the async method is free or not when the async method is being run. If the thread is free, the thread *can* be used to run the async method, but if there is another thread is free, another thread can be used. You don't need to worry about thread if you don't have shared data stored per thread.

Comment: @Sal The benefit using async method is you do not block a thread. When there's an `await`, the code under the hood will check whether the `Task` has completed, and if it is not, then give it a callback to say "tell me when you done", then return. By doing that, the thread has nothing left to execute, so the thread is free and can do something else. The task however will be executed by another thread or the same thread and call the callback to tell the caller "I'm done". In this way, one thread can run multiple tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an elegant solution without `Task.Run` if you can accept some restrictions.

```
...
//Get some data
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("myUrl").ConfigureAwait(false);
string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//Calculate result
...
```

Your cpu-bound code will run on some thread pool thread, if at least one async method before really runs asynchronously. If both finishes synchronously, then the following code would run on the calling thread. That may be a problem or may be not. (ie if naturally async code finishes synchronously, that may be because of some error. Then it may be possible that you didn't need to call cpu-intensive code at all.)

The second restriction is that you lose the original synchronisation context, and `await ProcessData()` may continue not on a calling thread.

You can read more about ConfigureAwait [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

Comment: For context, this is a windows service application. Does this mean that if I don't use ConfigureAwait(false) the cpu-bound code will not run on another thread pool thread?